# Honda engine swap

Tags: engine, honda, accord, swap

I'm working on a 2002 Honda accord 3.0 and done an engine swap.  I replaced the 3.0 with a 2005 Honda odyssey 3.5. Now the car will not go over 3000 rpms, what could cause this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you change out the ECU or get the one you have remapped for the 3.5? The fueling tables for the 3.0L won't work for the 3.5L. If you haven't updated the tune, you're most likely running the "new" engine lean, which could cause damage.